# Swift - Insert object/item / Add object/item in NSArray

Tags: object, swift, insert, nsarray, addition

I have this code:

```
var NToDel:NSArray = []
var addInNToDelArray = "Test1 \ Test2"
```

How to add `addInNToDelArray` in `NToDel:NSArray` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't - `NSArray` is an immutable array, and as such once instantiated it cannot be changed.
You should turn it into a `NSMutableArray`, and in that case it's as simple as:

```
NToDel.addObject(addInNToDelArray)
```

Alternatively, you can insert the value at instantiation time:

```
var NToDel:NSMutableArray = [addInNToDelArray]
```

but that's not about adding, it's about initializing - and in fact, after that line you cannot do any change to the array elements.

Note that there's an error in your string: the `\` character must be escaped as follows:

```
var addInNToDelArray = "Test1 \\ Test2"
```