# remove images from image array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an image array `var images: NSArray! = []` The maximum number of images in my array is 5 images. I want to be able to work with any number of images, so I extracted them

```
guard let imageOne = images[0] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageTwo = images[1] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageThree = images[2] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageFour = images[3] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageFive = images[4] as? UIImage else { return }
```

I want each index to be optional, So I can either use imageOne or imageOne and imageTwo but when I try to use less than 5 images, I get an index error. How do I make each index optional so that it is no longer grouped with the array and each index becomes its own image.

I initially have an array because I have a custom UIImagePicker that only takes arrays, but I want to upload the images to Firebase and Firebase does not take arrays, so I have to extract the images from the array.

Using a suggested answer below, I did this to my code:

```
        for (counter, img) in images.enumerated(){
                if counter == 0 {

                    func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
                        var randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)
                        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne!, 1.0)


                        let uploadRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
                        uploadRef.put(img as! UIImage, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                            error in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("successfully uploaded Image")

                                self.imageFileName = "\(randomName as String).jpg"

                                randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)

                                let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                    "image" : self.imageFileName,

                                ]

                                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).child(key).setValue(postObject)

                                print("Posted to Firebase. ")

                            } else{
                                print("Error uploading image")

                            }}

                    }
 if let pickedImage = img as?
                            UIImage{
                            uploadImage(image: pickedImage)

                                    }

                }
    }
```

Now, how do I check to see how many images are selected and call the function within every `if counter == num`

Comment: You already have the images stored in your array, why do you need to duplicate them as variables? Obviously if you have fewer than 5 things in the array and you access index [4] an error will occur.

Comment: @kpie that's what I am trying to avoid. I want to be able to access any index without an error occuring

Comment: If you want to use more than 5 images, why not define your array as [UIImage?] ?

Comment: @SahandTheGreat I want to use 5 images or less

Comment: This question is very unclear.  If you want to use less than five images, load a array with less than five images.  Not to mention, moving your array elements into their own variables, completely takes away the need/purpose of having a array.  Maybe give more information on why you needing to access your images in this manner?

Comment: It makes no sense, pardon me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for img in imgs  {
    //do something for each img
}
```

Don't copy individual array members out to variables. By iterating through the list you will do something with each image in the list without getting any index errors. If you need to treat each image differently you can use conditional branching with a counter.

```
let counter = 0
for img in imgs  {
    if counter == 0 {
        // do something for first img
    }
    if counter == 1 {
        // do something for second img
    }
    //...
    if counter == 4 {
        // do something for fifth img
    }
    counter += 1
}
```

Comment: There's no need to manage a `counter` index manually. Just use `for (counter, img) in imgs.enumerated()`. And do NOT just have a bunch of `if`s; use `else if` so that it doesn't have to do unnecessary evaluations.

Comment: @NRitH or a `switch` statement....but like you said just use `for (index, element) in imgs.enumerated(){}` it would be a better approach

Comment: My only issue with a `switch` is that it has to be exhaustive, and since you can't realistically be exhaustive with regular `Int`s, you need a `default` case, and that just adds unnecessary error-handling.

Comment: @Kpie I used your answer and updated by question. How do I go through the else if statements to see how many images are selected and then call the function within it

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't agree with the way you're going about this, this will answer your question:

First change `var images: NSArray! = []` to `var images: NSMutableArray! = []`

```
while images.count < 5{
    images.addObject(UIImage())
}
guard let imageOne = images[0] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageTwo = images[1] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageThree = images[2] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageFour = images[3] as? UIImage else { return }
guard let imageFive = images[4] as? UIImage else { return }
```

Comment: This does answer your question.  BUT you @OP should really rethink your implantation of this segment of code.   If I came across this in a code base I would have the biggest wtf face ever.

Comment: I get the error value of type 'NSArray' has no member append

Comment: Use a NSMutableArray, NSArray is not mutable (you can not 'append' elements to it) Same with NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary, just fyi

Comment: I'm kind of echoing Jacob, but it's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551325/swift-insert-object-item-add-object-item-in-nsarray I'll edit the post :)

Comment: NSMUtableArray still has no type append

Comment: im sorry but now it says nil is not compatible with argument type any

Comment: juelizabeth, please do yourself a favor and completely rethink your approach.

Comment: why don't you use an array of UIImages?

Comment: The best thing you could possibly do right now it to select all of your code in whatever you're working on and press the delete key, write it again. I've done it, it's helpful, change to what @kpie suggested and you'll be much more successful.

Comment: I am completely clueless here and I am not sure what other approaches to use. I updated my question explaining why I want to extract the images from the array

Comment: is there a way I can send you my view controller and have you take a look at it?

Comment: github / share it with bearacuda13@gmail.com on google drive / post your full code within your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147299/discussion-between-juelizabeth-and-bearacuda13).